# JavaFX WebView JDK Bug

Tags: java, html, javafx, webview, java-8

Hello I have a problem with JDK, I was using old JDK 1.8.0_77 which work well for WebView, 
it had only on problem which was probably due to old WebEngine library,
or what (because during using jQuery function for drag scroll of local HTML page it was tearing (fragmenting) my page).

I found out that this tearing problem is fixed in newest JDK 1.8.131! But after install, when I use it in my project,
I found out, that newest JDK have some other sort of bug in webview. I am using SVG with call up from HTML JAVA (`setMember()`), 
which is completely not working after start application (For older used JDK it was working well).
I found that up calls not working here after load, it do nothing, 
some kind of bug (I am clicking on html element which should call method, and it do nothing).

I also found out that it works, but only after clicking on button, which call method that again call `loadContent(String html)` method. 
But it is not solution, that if user wanna correctly work with appliaction, he firstly must click on button which call this method, to "fix" that bug.

I launch this after start(in `initialize()` method):

```
webEngine = webViews.getEngine();
String html = getHtmlMap("Areal");  //getHtmlMap - loads local html file

webEngine.documentProperty().addListener((obs, oldDoc, newDoc) -> {
    JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
    window.setMember("javaApp", new JSCallbackController());
    window.setMember("loadTimetable", new JSCallbackController());
});

webEngine.loadContent(html);
```

Also what I noticed between older and newer JDK, that my page is loaded also differently - in older its nicely load page, 
it means not so zoomed as it is loaded via newer JDK. Can anyone help me?

**NOTE**: works to JDK 1.8.0_92 (load well, but tearing drag scroll), from 1.8.102 above not working (load wrong,  but tearing drag scroll fixed)